# If $u:M \longrightarrow F$ is linear map then there is a linear map $v : E \longrightarrow F$ which extends $u$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $E$ and $F$ be a vectors space, $M$ a linear subspace of $E$, and $u$ a linear map of $M$ into
a vector space $F$. I want to prove that there is a linear map $v : E \longrightarrow F$ which extends $u$.

I can prove in the case that $M$ is a basis for $E$. In that case I couldn't prove it (where $M$ is a linear space arbitrary).

Comment: Note that the extension built here is not necessarily continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $M$ is a subspace of $E$, and $u:M\to F$ is linear.  Fix a basis $\mathcal B_0$ for $M$, and extend to a basis $\mathcal B$ of $E$.  Define $v:\mathcal B\to F$ by 
$$v(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}u(x) & \text{if }x\in\mathcal B_0\\
0 & \text{if }x\in\mathcal B\setminus\mathcal B_0.\end{array}\right.$$
Then extend $v$ linearly to obtain a map $E\to F$.  Such an extension must also be an extension of $u$.

Answer (score 1):

A basis is never a subspace.

**Hint:** Pick a basis on $M$ and extend it to a basis of $E$.